# How can I replace text in RichTextBox form another form?

Tags: c#, forms, replace, find, richtextbox

So I have a RichTextBox called `richTextBox1`, in a form named `XMLEditor` I want to be able to rename any chosen word in all parts of the rich text box with anything I want. (Like find and replace in notepad).

But I want to use another form called `Find` (It looks like Find & Replace in notepad) to have functions that will replace the words in the `richTextBox1` that is in `XMLEditor`.

The form named `Find` has a 2 textboxes and 1 button. The first textbox named `textBox1` will be used to choose the text you will replace while `textBox3` will be what the text is replaced with. And the button `button3` will replace the text while clicked.

How can I replace text in a `RichTextBox` from another form? How can I do this with these forms?

```
void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XMLEditor xmle = new XMLEditor();
    xmle.richTextBox1.Text = xmle.richTextBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text);
}
```

Comment: sent it via the constructor

Comment: `richTextBox1.Text = textBoxX.Text` Invoke it. Or do you mean `Text.Replace("some text to be replaced", "replace with");`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is pass the XMLEditor form as a parameter when constructing Find, and have a public XMLEditor method that can be used for interaction.

```
interface IFindAndReplace {
    void Replace(String s);
}

public class XMLEditor : IFindAndReplace {
    ...
    public void ShowFindAndReplaceForm() {
        Find findForm = new Find(this);
    }
    public void Replace(String s) {
        //Replace method here
    }
}

public class Find {
    IFindAndReplace parent;
    public Find(IFindAndReplace parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Replace(String s) {
        parent.Replace(s);
        //this will call Replace on the parent form.
    }
}
```

---

edited to use interfaces :)